# How to point RSS feed's links to items' correct url?

Tags: content-query-web-part, rss

I have a List of blogpost-like items, which are published through a Page on a public facing site. I'd like to provide a selection of these items as an simple RSS feed (Title & Description), so I have configured the Publishing Page's RSS settings to "Link RSS items directly to their files" and set up a Content Query Web Part, filtering the appropriate items, and enabling its RSS feed.

The problem is that the RSS feed's items (and the CQWP itself) link to the items' internal *Display Forms* instead of their public facing urls.

Any help on the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to customize the RSS that CQWP generates. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb608445.aspx) contains instructions.

Basically you need to create your own XSL file and register it in \Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\portnumber\wpresources\web.config.

Comment: Thanks - So far we have edited the rss.xsl file's value `<xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">` to point it to the desired url path. Once we're happy with the structure we'll register it in the web.config.